# In Android programming: How can I call a method that accepts arguments of type View?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Ok, so I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

And I've gotten to the `ActionBar` training. At this point, I have an app with an action bar and a button. The button is beside an edit text field, and if you press it, it just takes you to another view with the text you typed in.

Now, I'm trying to call the same method that takes you to that 2nd view using one of the action bar menu options. The handler for that is in the main activity source code, a snippet of which i paste here:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                sendMessage();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
//              openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I want try and call the sendMessage method in one of the cases in the switch operation, but I don't know what arguments to put in. When the button is clicked, the handler is in the xml file:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

I don't know how that works. Is what I'm trying to do impossible? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not call directly. `Android` calls it when you press the `Button` where do you declare `android:onClick property`. If you want to call it in any case just pass a null parameter and check against null values

Comment: @StarSky 's answer works, but I think this is the real answer I'm looking for. The most efficient as well. Thanks @blackbelt!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a secondary function `sendRealMessage` and in your switch call this function.

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
   sendRealMessage();
}

public void sendRealMessage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Another way is to call your function passing a null value `sendMessage(null)` since it's not directly used by the function.

Comment: Oh my gosh that's so...genius! Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can name the button at the xml with an id.

`android:id="+@id/buttonnamehere`

Then from your code call the button and perform a click action use methods:

`Button mybut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnamehere);`

And for the click:

`mybut.performClick();`

Answer (score 0):

```
U can Read the same button As View by 

{

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
 Button btnXyz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
sendMessage(btnXyz)

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly call sendMessage() method by passing view as null.